# error in sfWidgetFormDate()

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a date field in my MySQL table with the value '0000-00-00'. When using sfWidgetFormDate() to display the value on my webform, it somehow defaults to November 30 with an empty year. Any ideas what could be happening? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `sfWidgetFormDate()` uses a `strtotime()` to convert the value to date. According to comments on [php.net strtotime manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#94466) this function generates different output for "zero" value on different systems and PHP versions (one of this values is in fact 30th Nov, year -1).

Maybe you should check the value before passing to the widget and change it to `null`.